# while loop for sum of diagonals in a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

why does d1 come up to be equal to 0 al the time, whereas the d2 while loop gives the correct answer??

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int r, c, i, j, a[100][100], d1, d2;

   cout<<"Number of rows you want in the array";

   cin>>r;

   cout<<"Number of columns you want in the array";

   cin>>c;

   //**1) constructing the matrix

   for(i=0; i<r; i++){

      for(j=0; j<c; j++){  //**since the columns change while a particular row is filled

         cout<<"a["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]::";

         cin>>a[i][j];
      }
   }


   cout<<"The matrix is displayed below\n";


   for(i=0; i<r; i++){

      for(j=0; j<c; j++){

         cout<<a[i][j]<<"    ";


      }
      cout<<"\n";
   }


   //**2) calculating the sum of the diagonals


   //** the matrix should be a square one otherwise this program won't be possible, not possible

   i=0;

   d1=0;


   if(i<r){//**Left to right: where the index of both, rows and columns remains the same

      i=j;

      d1 = d1 + a[i][j];

      i++;
   }

   cout<<"\n\t Sum of diagonals from left to right = "<<d1;

   j=0;

   i=r-1;

   d2=0;

   while(i>=0 && j<c){

      d2 = d2 + a[i][j];

      i--;

      j++;
   }


   cout<<"\n\t Sum of diagonals from right to left = "<<d2;




   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(i<r)` needs to be `while ( i < r)`. Typo, maybe? – R Sahu 8 mins ago   Delete

Comment: Also, at that point, `j` is uninitialzed! Maybe you need a `j = r - 1;` line just before?

Answer (score 0):

As the code you provided is a mess. Here is some general code that sums the diagonals of a matrix.

Consider a matrix with index i for row and j for column. If the matrix is square then only one solution exists, when i==j therefore it is sufficient to say

```
double sum_diag = 0;
size_t rows = 10;
size_t cols = 10;
double** matrix = (malloc ...);
for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    sum_diag += matrix[i][i];
```

For the diagonal going right to left (not sure what that means mathematically if anything).

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
    sum_diag += matrix[j][cols-j-1];
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you want to use `malloc` in a C++ answer?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it..., if you want to use new then go ahead...

Comment: I'd start with `std::vector` and work my way down from there.